# Finding tangent to curve fitting sampled data.

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Let $(x_i, y_i)$ be a finite sample of points.  I want to find the slope of the tangent at $x$ to a curve "best fit" to the given data. In my problem area, (see context below), the simplest of techniques is to perform an $L^2$ minimization to find the closest parabola to the curve.  Then its derivative at the point $x$ can be computed.  There are various models that suggest different family of curves from which a best one can be chosen to fit the data as well.

[image]

My question is: Suppose I only assume that the sample points satisfy
$$y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$$
where $f$ is smooth and $\epsilon_i$ are iid normal random variables.  Are there any techniques for finding a best function $f$, or really just the derivative of $f$ at some point $x$ without using any model related to the underlying problem.  I am thinking of something like a "minimum entropy curve".

The above picture is the general situation.  A series of point that lie close to a curve that has "very little variation".  Perhaps minimizing both the $L^2$ distance, and the energy of the curve is the proper technique.

Context: This problem arises in Math Finance but I believe it is more general. In that context though it is the issue of finding the at the money skew to the implied volatility curve.